# Can I implement Singleton Design Pattern like this in Scheme?

Tags: design-patterns, scheme

I have little knowledge about design pattern, today I learnt the Singleton design pattern, so I tried to
implement it in Scheme like this

```
(define nil '())
(define Singleton
  (let ((instance nil))
    (lambda ()
      (if (null? instance)
          (let ((a 0))
            (define (dispatch msg)
              (cond ((eq? msg 'get)
                     (lambda () a))
                    ((eq? msg 'set)
                     (lambda (v) 
                       (begin (set! a v)
                              'ok)))))
              (set! instance dispatch)))
      instance)))
(define a (Singleton))
(define b (Singleton))
(eq? a b);;#t
((a 'set) 3)
((b 'get));;3
```

is my understand and implementation to this design pattern right?

Comment: I'm not a DP expert, but it seems right to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation is correct, because `(eq? a b)` is `#t`.

I would simplify it a little bit (although this is not Code Review) like so:

1. no need to have a flag if it's the first call; just define the dispatcher once and constantly return a reference to it
2. no need to define `nil`, `'()` will do
3. I personally prefer to use `(a 'set 3)` rather than `((a 'set) 3)`
4. In this case, it's clearer to use `case` instead of `cond`

so

```
(define Singleton
  (let ((a 0))                     ; instance variables
    (define (get) a)
    (define (set v) (set! a v) 'ok)
    (define (dispatch msg . args)  ; dispatcher procedure
      (case msg
        ((get) (apply get args))
        ((set) (apply set args))
        (else  (error "unknown message"))))
    (lambda () dispatch)))         ; return dispatch procedure
```

then

```
(define a (Singleton))
(define b (Singleton))
(eq? a b)    ;;  #t
(a 'set 3)   ;; 'ok
(b 'get)     ;;   3
```

Comment: You could just return dispatch, and not use the parens when defining a and b.

Comment: @Rptx Yes true. But I guess that's not really implementing a singleton pattern then.